# Debian install telegraf the data confusion

Tags: telegraf

1. I am Follow site guidelines install telegraf   want to sent data to influxdb
   wget https://dl.influxdata.com/telegraf/releases/telegraf_1.20.3-1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i telegraf_1.20.3-1_amd64.deb

2.but the log and data is confusion like that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxfHf.jpg)

3.that my conf

```
 `[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
   quiet = false
   logtarget = "file"
   logfile = "/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log"
  hostname = "test1"
  omit_hostname = false
[[outputs.influxdb]]
urls = ["http://10.20.5.8:8086"]
   database = "iaas_test"
   database_tag = "iaas_test"
   skip_database_creation = true
   user_agent = "telegraf"
[[inputs.cpu]]
  percpu = true
  totalcpu = true
  collect_cpu_time = false
  report_active = false
[[inputs.mem]]`
```

i guess zh_CN code quretion   but mylocal  is en_us utf-8
and i search all the conf not hava about cn

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use HTTP to send data to the backend influxdb, the gzip format is not supported by default. This can be fixed by modifying the `content_encoding` setting to `identity`, like so:

```
## HTTP Content-Encoding for write request body, can be set to "gzip" to
## compress body or "identity" to apply no encoding.
content_encoding = "identity"
```

Comment: that will slove this problem